# SharePoint Web Apps and single ADFS Relying Party Trust

Tags: sharepoint-server, adfs, security-token-service

I have a big doubt in how to make the following configuration work correctly.

I have 2 SharePoint farms, one application per each farm:

1. Dev Enviroment   - My web app (dev version) https://url.comdev
2. Prod Environment - My web app (prod version) https://url.com

The two applications are identical and both environment are accessed by users coming a unique Active Directory (we don't have a dev user domain).

I have asked the creation of two relying party trust in an existing ADFS and I have configured a standard trusted token issuer on SharePoint. I was given a single relaying party trust configured in the following way:

*WS Federation Passive Endpoint*: https://url.com/_trust/

*Identifiers*:

- https://url.com/_trust/
- https://url.comdev/_trust/
- uri:sp:url.com
- uri:sp:url.comdev

Given $ap* my SP Identity Trusted Token Issuers, my configuration was in Prod:

```
$id1 = "urn:sp:url.com"
$uri1 = new-object System.Uri("https://url.com")
$ap_prod.ProviderRealms.Add($uri1, $id1)
$ap_prod.Update()
```

And in Dev:

```
$id2 = "urn:sp:url.comdev"
$uri2 = new-object System.Uri("https://url.comdev")
$ap_dev.ProviderRealms.Add($uri2, $id2)
$ap_dev.Update()
```

Such configuration was not working in Dev, after sts authenitcation I was redirected to https://url.com/trust/.

Searching online I discovered the parameter *UseWReplyParameter*, and I run command only the following **only in Dev**:

```
$ap_dev.UseWReplyParameter = $true
$ap_dev.Update()
```

The configuration not seems working. Is this correct or do I have to configure the same way also the Prod farm? Which are the potential problem if I don't.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i am thinking, You need the separate ADFS packages for each farm.I dont think it is recommend way to use the single package for two farm.

With in Single farm, you can do it the way you are implementing using the `usewreplyparameter`.

Comment: Ok, so I actually need to ask the ADFS admins to review their package configuration. Is there any documentation on it to use as reference? :)

Comment: Other quick question. The WS Passive Endpoint for SharePoint web app needs to be formatted as  **_trust/** or is it fine to write it as **_trust** the same way? My lack of knowledge on the subject tent to confuse the details.

Comment: it should be like this .com/_trust/

Comment: Thank you again! May I ask you why?

Comment: i am not sure why but here is MSFT: In the WS-Federation Passive protocol URL field, type the name of the web application URL, and append /_trust/ (for example, https:// app1.contoso.com/_trust/). Click Next" https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh305235.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Phase3